# Property of injected service undefined during karma test

Tags: angular, observable, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a component say *notificationComponent*, which has a property  say *`notes[]`*, it listens to a service say *notificationService* which has a observable `noteAdded` which broadcasts all the notifications sent to the service.

The way I am planning to test the *notificationComponent* is: Every time a notification is pushed to the *notificationService*, the *notificationComponent* should populate `notificationComponent.notes[]` through a function listening to the *`notificationService.noteAdded`*.

this is the component :

```
    import...;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-notifications',
      templateUrl: './notifications.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./notifications.component.css']
    })
    export class NotificationsComponent {

      notes: BentoAlertItemOptions[];

      constructor(private _notifications: NotificationsService) {
        this.notes = [];

        _notifications.noteAdded.subscribe(note => {
          this.notes.push(note);
        });
      }

      closeAlert($event:any) {
        console.info('Alert #', $event, ' is being closed');
      }
    }
```

NotificationService : 
    import..

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {
  private _notifications = new ReplaySubject<any>(5);
  public noteAdded = this._notifications.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    console.log("notification service constructor");
  }

  public add(notification: BentoAlertItemOptions) {
    console.log("added: ", notification);
    this._notifications.next(notification);
  }
}
```

This is my spec file :

```
describe('NotificationsComponent', () => {
  let component: NotificationsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NotificationsComponent>;
  let testBedService:NotificationsService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        NotificationsComponent,
        MockComponent({
          selector: 'bento-alert',
          inputs: ['items'],
          outputs :['close']
        }),
      ],
      providers: [ NotificationsService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    testBedService = TestBed.get(NotificationsService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NotificationsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  //THE TEST THAT FAILS
  fit('should push to notes[] for notes added event on the subscribed-service', () => {
    let addedNote:any;

    addedNote = {
      type     :'success',
      msg      : 'Moduled saved!',
      timeout  : 2500,
      closeable: true
    }

    testBedService.add(addedNote);

    expect(true);
  });
});
```

Although when I test this I get an error saying `cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` implying `notificationComponent.notificationService.noteAdded` is undefined.

Not sure why this is happening, also I am using the real service in the test as don't see why I should mock a simple service like `notificationService`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, added the missing imports and semicolons, and ran your test successfully. So the errors must be in the imports.

Comment: I figured it out , it didn't like me mocking the 3rd party bento component, so I had to import the entire real bento module into the test bed, thanks for you comment

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to find what was happening , seems like it didn't like me mocking the 3rd party bento component:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [
            NotificationsComponent,
            MockComponent({
              selector: 'bento-alert',
              inputs: ['items'],
              outputs :['close']
            }),
          ],..
```

So I imported the real module instead and it worked:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        NotificationsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BentoModule
      ],..
```